# What is the difference between "misapprehension" and "apprehension"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

I can't quite get  my head around the difference between **misapprehension**  and its opposite **apprehension**.

I understand the latter, but the former still eludes me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apprehension is not usually used as the opposite of misapprehension.

**Misapprehension** is another word for *misunderstanding* - "A mistaken belief about or interpretation of something".

**Apprehension** can mean "understanding", but is usually used to refer to a feeling of fear or misgiving about a future event.

Answer (score 2):

"Misapprehension" only negates one meaning of "apprehension":

> misapprehension — a mistaken belief about or interpretation of something
>
> apprehension — understanding; grasp

The other meanings of *apprehension* are generally not relevant to the meaning of *misapprehension*.

Usage examples from the same dictionary I grabbed the definitions:

> the pure apprehension of the work of art
>
> she must have been laboring under the misapprehension that you are nice

Answer (score -1):

So, the way I take it is that *mis*apprehension is that you are worried about something ***for no real reason***. So if apprehension is to be worried about something before it happens the misapprehension is to be worried in advance about something that is actually not something to be worried about?

Comment: While this is correct, you should include a citation for definitions. Well done and welcome.

Comment: This is not correct at all. Misapprehension is misunderstanding, not improper worrying.